# Run a full Flask server under pytest to handle HTTP requests on a given port

Tags: python, flask, pytest, werkzeug

Normally, when testing an endpoint, the [Flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/testing/) recommend doing something like this:

```py
import pytest
from my_project import create_app

@pytest.fixture()
def app():
    app = create_app()

    yield app


@pytest.fixture()
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()
```

and then using the `client` fixture in a test like so:

```py
def test_ping(client):
    response = client.get("/foobar")
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

However, in some very niche cases, the code which handles the `/foobar` endpoint might need to make a HTTP call back to the Flask server (imagine it imports a poorly-designed library which needs to fetch some data from an endpoint and it doesn't allow you to inject a custom fetcher, so all you can do is to specify a custom URL). How can I run the entire Flask server in a background thread?

Comment: I'm confused about what you're doing. You say "the code which handles the /foobar endpoint might need to make a HTTP call back to the Flask server", which doesn't make sense to me - the code handling requests to that endpoint is already running on the server, so why do you need to make an HTTP request to the same server? If you mean you're calling some other API then you can at least design your app in a way so that it's easy to test by injecting dependencies.

Comment: It's a niche thing. My code calls a certain library which needs to make requests back to another API endpoint. Reworking my code to avoid calling this library during tests would solve the issue, but, in this particular case, I'd have a harder time maintaining my integration tests, because I'd need store a lot of mock data which is kinda' brittle and annoying to refresh or use something like https://www.mbtest.org to serve what this other endpoint needs to provide, but then I'd have to run Mountebank as a separate process. Running a full server in memory in the background is common in Golang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose, it used to be possible to [leverage](https://gist.github.com/eruvanos/c370b04e1be18b89d1babec188495c32) the `werkzeug.server.shutdown` mechanism. Unfortunately, this has been deprecated and [removed](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1752).

However, this mechanism isn't strictly necessary. If you only need the server to start once before running the tests (at the `session` level), then you can run it as a `daemon` background thread and you can skip `thread.join()` because, when the tests finish, it will be the only thread left running and the Python process exits when only `daemon` threads are left. Details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects). There is some potential for race conditions if the server doesn't get a chance to start before the tests execute, but that can be "fixed" with a bit of sleep...

This is the code ended up with in my `conftest.py`:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def app():
    app = create_app()

    thread = Thread(target=app.run, daemon=True, kwargs=dict(host='localhost', port=5000))
    thread.start()

    yield app


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()
```

All the tests which need this full-fledged Flask server to be up and running must to use the `client` fixture which depends on the `app` fixture.